# Unable to call OAC(Oracle Analytics Cloud) REST API services using cURL tool in Oracle Business Intelligence Publisher 12.2.1.2.0 server

Tags: bi-publisher

I was following below document to Access the Oracle Analytics Service(OAC) REST resources.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/api-platform-cloud/apfra/UsecURL.html

Steps I have done:

1. downloaded and installed cURL s/w
2. set the cURL environment variable, CURL_CA_BUNDLE
   3.Run cURL from command prompt from local machine
   4.curl -u XXXXusername:XXXPASSWORD -H "Accept:application/json" -X GET https://erpoacdev4.gaptech.com/ui/analytics/saw.dll?bipublisherEntry&Action=open&itemType=.xdo&bipPath=%2FPurchasing%2FRPT_POC.xdo&path=%2Fshared%2FPurchasing%2FRPT_POC.xdo

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSmp5.png)

Please help me on the issue.

Thanks,
Pullareddy M